# R-square vs. NFI?

Tags: regression, structural-equation-modeling, partial-least-squares

I ran a path model (no latent variables) in smartPLS3. It's not a complicated model. But after the analysis was computed, I checked the model fit measures. R-squares are small (all of them < .3), but on the other hand, SRMR < .08 and NFI is 93% (good).

Now SRMR and NFI indicate good fit of the model but R-square's are small. How can we justify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data--model correspondence does not imply high *R*^2; they are independent issues.  If little variance is explained by your predictors in the population, your estimated *R*^2 should reflect that.  If your model is correctly specified, your fit indices should reflect that.